# Craft CMS Preview Error

Tags: preview

We're using Craft pro 3.6.11.2 , when we click on the preview button, the preview loads ok for a few seconds, but then seems to load the homepage template repeatedly which results in the browser tab crashing.

Is there anyway to debug this?  I can see some errors in the console before the page crashes:

[image: browser errors]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check you have setup the preview url or not and then try to clear the cache. then Just try to update the craft cms.